# What is the name of the technique where the pitch of the instrumental or vocal line slides smoothly between notes?

Tags: voice, terminology, instruments

Okay, I have been trying to find the word for this vocal trick/note trick for so freaking long. I don't even know if there's a word for it but it's in so many songs spanning the history of recorded music that there *has to be a word for it!* So I'm wondering if any of you know what this is called or just what something similar to this little note/tonal trick is called. I've included five really obvious uses of the trick but there are so many more, so if more examples are needed to pinpoint what this is, let me know!

Most clear example: 0:40 to 0:49 (and repeated throughout song) of [Baby by Os Mutantes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--uRcXZQcoI)

More examples:
0:43 to 0:50 of [Mr. Maker by the Kooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFBZ4UKdtPQ)

0:24 to 0:36 of [In an Aeroplane Over the Sea by Neutral Milk Hotel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hD6_QXwKesU)

0:00 to 0:20 of [Dead Record Player by Dr. Dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_3IpP4DZqk) and the repeated slide-note throughout the song

0:32 to 0:42 & 1:05 to 1:15 of [(Dee Dee) Be My Girl by Dee Dee Sharp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Duyj2lARfb0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glissando or portamento.

Glissando is moving up or down existing notes - as in the strings of a harp, frets of a guitar or keys on a piano.

Portamento is moving from one note to another with no gaps - as in a trombone slide, a violin string or indeed a voice.

Both tend to happen smoothly.

I quote both, as generally an instrument will do one or the other, although voice can do both. Here, it would appear that the voice is 'portamento-ing'.

Comment: But on trombone, a portamento is called a glissando.  No point in disputing it. And, to confuse matters further, trombone CAN do a 'distinct notes' glissando.  Start on middle Bb in 1st position, lip up while moving the slide out.  You'll get something close to a Bb major scale.

Comment: Sadly,  *gliss* is used more and more to indicate *portamento* , and I don't recall anyone ever referring to the opening of Rhapsody in Blue as anything other than "clarinet glissando."  Sic transit mundi.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - isn't it written as a gliss?

Comment: Harp has always called one thing a gliss, trombone another.  'Portamento' implies an expressive transition between notes.
I'm not sure this ever bothered anyone except narrow-vision textbook writers until the DX7 de facto defined the terms for a new generation of musician, many of them with little hands-on experience of real instruments.

Comment: Tim,  The original piano solo (IMSLP) is not marked "gliss,"   and wikipedia says "The opening clarinet glissando came into being during rehearsal when; "... as a joke on Gershwin, [Ross] Gorman (Whiteman's virtuoso clarinettist) played the opening measure with a noticeable glissando, adding what he considered a humorous touch to the passage. Reacting favourably to Gorman's whimsy, Gershwin asked him to perform the opening measure that way at the concert and to add as much of a 'wail' as possible."" ref Schwartz, Charles, (1979). Gershwin: His Life and Music. New York City: Da Capo Press.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - true - I can decide on keys whether it'll be a gliss or a port, but technically they're different in that gliss uses only diatonic or chromatic notes, depending on the instrument, I guess, while port goes through notes 'in the cracks' as well. But it's a bit of a grey area. Somewhat reminiscent of vibrato/tremolo - depending who's being asked, especially if it's guitarists.

Comment: It's not just legato? I mean for vocals there's a fine line between legato singing and portamento.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now have an actual word (well, two words) to use when searching for songs that have this little vocal/instrumental trick. I very much appreciate your response - it's been years of looking for the right word!

Comment: @ToddWilcox - legato means joined, but most legato singing (and playing) is done smoothly, but without sliding from one note to the next in pitch.. That's where portamento takes over.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox I disagree.  I spend a lot of time training singers in the difference between legato, legato-with-diction and a 'swoop'.  I have to tolerate the swoop in some styles of solo singing.  In choral singing, my mission is to eradicate it!

Comment: @tim - how about _legato_ ?

Comment: @Stinkfoot - all gliss and all portamento are legato, but not all legato is gliss or portamento. Bit like all poodles are dogs, but not all dogs are poodles.

Answer (score 0):

In music performance and notation, the term for instrumental or vocals that are sung/played smoothly and connected is *Legato*.

Comment: Did you listen to the linked audio clips?